# Defining a char array in c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Having such a super simple *char array* definition:

```
const int g_msgbuf_size = 200;
char g_msgbuf[g_msgbuf_size];
```

giving me an totally unreasonable error:

```
error C2057: expected constant expression
```

on the *second* line while compiling in `MSVC 2019`.

When i try the code on any other `c++` `compiler` like https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler or http://cpp.sh/ everything goes well - I get no errors as expected.

Why does the `MSVC 2019` makes me problems?

Comment: It wants this: `constexpr int g_msgbuf_size = 200;`

Comment: You have correct code. `g_msgbuf_size` is a constant expression in your case. It should work in MSVC 2019 . Maybe a bug in MSVC 2019 or most probably you made a mistake while pasting the code here and in your real code(that you have not pasted here) `g_msgbuf_size` is not a consant expression.

Comment: Are you sure you actually have `const int g_msgbuf_size = 200;`? That is a constant expression due to legacy rules, but something like `const int g_msgbuf_size = my_function();` stops being a constant expression. A constant expression is stricter than just `const`.

Comment: It's an error in C but not in C++: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2057?view=msvc-160

Comment: Note: onlinegdb fronts GCC, and GCC is MUCH more forgiving than Visual Studio when it comes to what it will accept for an array size due to its variable length arrays extension.

Comment: @m88 That's odd since VLA:s are actually allowed since C99. I guess VS2019 isn't quite there yet. :-)

Comment: MSVS ignored C99. I'm not sure what C Standard it supports now that VLAs are optional, but I bet I can find out.

Comment: [Looks like they support C11 and C17, jumping C99 completely.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @user4581301 It is supposed to support C17 - but not VLA:s it seems: https://godbolt.org/z/r14GxhW6s

Comment: Where are those things defined?  Can you provide a [mcve]?  For example `const int g_msgbuf_size = 200;` _isn't_ a constant expression if it's defining a class member.

Comment: Suggested fix: `char g_msgbuf[200]; const size_t g_msgbuf_size  = sizeof g_msgbuf;`

Comment: @darek_911 I tested the sample in VS 2019 but no error. Did you run the code in .c file instead of .cpp file? This error  occurs in .c files.